# Learning C# quickly gathering all necessary concepts

Tags: c#, clr

I want to learn .NET and I have 2 weeks time of this. I have sound knowledge of CLR, Assemblies and certain basics. I have a copy of "CLR via C#". But I need to learn advanced C# concepts like delegates, reflection, generics and so on. And then I need to quickly jump into coding. Remember, I have 2 weeks time.
I suppose a quick grasp of C# advanced concepts and then some thorough coding practice is the need of the hour.

Can you suggest me on:
1) My approach.
2) Sites or books to learn these advanced C# concepts fast.
3) Practicing the things learnt by coding....suggestion on practice/programming questions. Since I also believe one can only learn any language by practicing it.

Please pour in your suggestions.

Regards,
Justin Samuel.

Comment: Please list your previous experience. 2 weeks is a VERY short time.

Comment: I have 2.8 years experience. I have done a small project during my college days in .NET but it was way back. Now I want to learn the language conceptually.

Comment: on the other hand, consider this: http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Joe Albahari's book ["C# in a Nutshell"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527570) (Disclaimer: I know the author, but I would recommend regardless). Joe's [site](http://www.albahari.com/) has lots of useful stuff.

Jon Skeet's articles + book: ["C# in Depth"](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/)

Andrew Troelsen's ["Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform, Fourth Edition"](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590598849)

**Free, online material:**

- [Microsoft webcasts and virtual labs](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/msdnvisualcsharp.aspx)
- Noah Coad's blog has a [good list of C# resources](http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/05/20/c-resources.aspx)
- [Microsoft's Ramp Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/default.aspx)
- SO: [C# Training videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100772/c-training-videos)
- SO: [Is there any one website which contains many good C# screencasts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155393/is-there-any-one-website-which-contains-many-good-c-screencasts)

Comment: That's not a good reason for a downvote.

Comment: Any reason for suggesting the .NET 3.0 edition of Pro C#, which will only cover C# 2? Here's the link to the .NET 3.5 / C# 3 version: http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590598849

Comment: I'd second the recommendation for C# in a Nutshell, btw.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I thought that edition seems old! I've updated the link.

Comment: you know the Albahari brothers?! cool.. best book i've ever seen. actully the only theoretical useful book i've ever seen :D do you know whether they gonna print a forth edition? and will it be alright if i write to you a few mistakes in the book? ^_^"

Comment: @Itay: The 4th Edition is due out in Jan 2010. I can highly recommended it. I believe Jon Skeet is also currently producing an updated version of C# in Depth

Comment: This is a good answer, and i apologize for downvoting. I hope you can forgive me?

Comment: @RCIX: I didn't take it personally!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [C# 2005: The Base Class Library](http://www.dotnet2themax.com/blogs/fbalena/PermaLink,guid,6d4703fa-edb4-441d-ae2a-dd9bc1303689.aspx) by Francesco Balena. Its a bit of an older book, but I found it to be an amazing read. I learnt a ton with it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to download some open source projects from [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/), and start debugging. You will better understand the internals this way...

Answer (score 1):

Once you know most of the basics, take a look at [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) to see all sorts of cool but slightly esoteric features.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link, 
http://sharpertutorials.com/tutorials/ 
This site having hands on guides for programming areas includes

**1. Introduction to C#**

**2. Intermediate C# Tutorials,**

**3. Advanced C# Tutorials**

**4. Object Orientation**

**5. Real World Object Orientated Programming**

**6. Testing and Debugging**

**7. Security and Encryption**

**8. Using .Net Assemblies**

**9. Software Engineering Principles**

**..........etc**

Comment: this link is no more...! its dead!

Answer (score -1):

In the question "[List of Freely Available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)", there's a link to the book [Illustrated C# 2008](http://www.ebook3000.com/Illustrated-C--2008_18267.html). This book offers a complete intruduction for everything in C#, from the most basic things like classes and methods all the way up to delegates, anonymous types, and event handlers. The good thing? you don't spend *a dime*!

Miscellaneus SO links:

- [Lambdas tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439541/delegates-and-lambdas-and-linq-oh-my)
- [More lambda tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376/what-is-a-good-use-of-lambda-expressions-and-how-can-i-learn-to-use-them)
- [Anonymous types explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635435/a-simple-and-succinct-definiton-and-explanation-of-anonymous-types-in-c) (asked specifically for this question)

Comment: It was working for me till now, odd....

Comment: Yes, 'Illustrated C#' link is broken.

Comment: Found an alternate link.

Comment: I think it would be worth renaming the links to make it clear why they're there.

Comment: +1 for the eBook link, -1 for the fun, yet useless, link names.

Comment: There i renamed them. Better? Please upvote me now... It's a perfectly great answer~

Comment: Your downvote on Mitch, and more importantly the reason for it ("My answer is better") has probably killed your chances of this answer getting anywhere

Comment: I fixed it! boy, no one has a sense of humor anymore....

Comment: Thats not a sense of humour, its arrogance.

Comment: I didn't mean it that way, and i'm truly sorry to have it come out that way. As i said, i was just trying to be funny, and the downvote was really a bad thing to do (which is why i fixed it). I hope people have the kindness to realize i have hopefully fixed the error of **my** (not their) ways and remove their downvotes. (I don't mean to sound condescending, arrogant, or anytihn else like that at all, i just went overboard trying to point out that no one else offered a free solution)

Comment: Well, can see you took this quite a lot to heart (These were my views, you don't need to be forgiven for anything). Will +1 you. Just next time all you have to do is simply state that your solution is free. Down vote for things that are going to cause actual harm if someone listens, or something more along those lines.