# what does the following syntax mean in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I learn something new everyday about C# and came across this construct. I am not 100% sure what it does, so can someone please explain it:

```
new { Name = "John"}
```

This was used where a string was expected as an argument to a method call.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an object initializer for an anonymous class. It constructs an object with a single property, Name, with value "John." Since you have no way to refer to the object, you would use it right away, as in a LINQ statement or as a parameter as you mentioned.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635435/a-simple-and-succinct-definiton-and-explanation-of-anonymous-types-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Its a new anonymous type with the property `Name` set to the string `"John"`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a newer syntax known as Anonymous Types. You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks to me like its creating an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with one property (Name, of type string).

But saying that it's used where a string was expected has me a little confused.