# What is a Lambda?

Tags: language-agnostic, lambda, computer-science, terminology

Could someone provide a good description of what a Lambda is?  We have a tag for them and they're on the secrets of C# question, but I have yet to find a good definition and explanation of what they are in the first place.

Comment: How about [Wikipedia's lambda calculus article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) for a start? Then [Wikipedia's functional programming article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming_language) as a followup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a lambda (function)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function)

Comment: amda expression explained [here](https://chaseyourjava.blogspot.in/2017/11/lamda-expression-in-java-8.html) 
 beautifully.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Closures, lambdas, and anonymous functions are not necessarily the same thing.

An anonymous function is any function that doesn't have (or, at least, need) its own name.

A closure is a function that can access variables that were in its lexical scope when it was declared, even after they have fallen *out* of scope.  Anonymous functions do not necessarily have to be closures, but they are in most languages and become rather less useful when they aren't.

A lambda is..  not quite so well defined as far as computer science goes.  A lot of languages don't even use the term; instead they will just call them closures or anon functions or invent their own terminology.  In LISP, a lambda is just an anonymous function.  In Python, a lambda is an anonymous function specifically limited to a single expression; anything more, and you need a named function.  Lambdas are closures in both languages.

Comment: the term might be intended to imply lambda calculus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus

Comment: Wow I with I had more than one upvote to give this question. I've seen so many technical answers bogged down in terminology, but this one is concise and makes the point immediately.

Comment: A region where some variable can exist (i.e., a scope) defined by the structure of your code (i.e., lexically).  For example, in most languages, a function defines a lexical scope; any variable declared inside the function is inaccessible outside of it.

Answer (score 19):

Also called closures or anonymous functions..
I found the best description [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Closure.html). Basically, inline block of code that can be passed as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 18):

"Lambda" refers to the [Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) or to a specific lambda expression.  Lambda calculus is basically a branch of logic and mathematics that deals with functions, and is the basis of [functional programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

~ William Riley-Land

Answer (score 8):

It's just an anonymous function declared inline, most typically assigned to a delegate when you don't want to write a full-fledged function.

In languages like lisp/scheme, they're often passed around quite liberally as function parameters, but the idiom in C# typically finds lambdas used only for lazy evaluation of functions, as in linq, or for making event-handling code a bit terser.

Answer (score 5):

There's not really such a thing as 'a lambda' in programming. It depends on the language, etc.

In short, normally a language that 'has lambdas' uses the term for anonymous functions or, in some cases, closures. Like so, in Ruby:

```
f = lambda { return "this is a function with no name" }
puts f.call
```

Answer (score 4):

In response to the previous answers:
-The important thing about anonymous functions is not that they dont require a name.
-Closures are a separate concept.
-A gigantic wikipedia article is not making this any clearer.

Here's my answer in 3 parts:
1. A lambda is a function which is also an expression. This is the important thing.
2. Many languages which implement so-called "lambdas" add some *syntactic sugar* to make writing these short functions easier and faster, but this is not required.
3. Some languages may require that a lambda has *no side effects*. That would be a more pure lambda in the functional sense.

When a function is an expression, it's a "first class citizen" within the language. I can do all the important things with it:

```
x = lambda(){ return "Hello World"; }

doit( 1, 2, lambda(a,b){ return a > b; }, 3 )

x = (lambda(a){ return a+1; }) + 5  // type error, not syntax error

(lambda(a,b){ print(a); log(b); })( 1, 2 )  // () is valid operator here
```

Answer (score 1):

Clipped from wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda#Lambda.2C_the_word

In programming languages such as Lisp and Python, lambda is an operator used to denote anonymous functions or closures, following lambda calculus usage.

Comment: I guess you meant this line: In programming languages such as Lisp and Python, lambda is an operator used to denote anonymous functions or closures, following lambda calculus usage.

I'd already scanned the article but missed that.