# Where does the x come from in this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

So I was looking around on the internet reading up on sorting techniques and I stumbled on to lambda.
Now i'm not completly sure how it works and i couldnt find any tutorials that broke it down to my level.

This is what im trying to break down.

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(x => new MailAddress(x).Host).ToList();
```

So I get that I create a variable named sorted and this will be the variable that hold the sorted items from the list.

This is the part I dont understand

```
OrderBy(x => new MailAddress(x).Host)
```

Where does x come from and what exactly does the lambda expression mean? `=>`
Its not like this expression `!=` which means NOT.
And I get that it sorts by host so Yahoo, GMAIL & Hotmail.

Comment: I think your question **may** be "what is a lambda expression?"

Comment: "x" is just an identifier

Comment: MS Documentation: [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) x is called an input parameter

Comment: The answer here is also useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832337/interview-what-is-lambda-expression

Comment: If anyone could write this lambda expression out as a delegate I would be very happy! Then i could actually see how it breaks down, tha anotomy behind the code.

Comment: @ChristofferNilsson, Check the documentation linked to above. they break everything down.

Comment: The MSDN post was super confusing to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simplest terms, x is a variable that you declare.

So it reads **"x such that x is"**... Whatever expression you are trying to convey based on the input and output parameter of your query.

To give you another example:

```
var sorted = list.Where(x => x.Name == "Foo").ToList();
```

This reads as "**x such that x is equal to Foo**". And this will return all list with Name property that is equal to Foo.

To further explain this, lets look into the one of the overloaded Enumerable method which is "**Where**". According to MSDN:

[image]

The actual syntax is:

```
Where<TSource>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
Func<TSource, bool> predicate
```

To give another example lets declare a List of integer. Our goal is to get all even integers:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

Now to query all integers who are even numbers, we will use the one of the overloaded version of Where extension methods, using lambda syntax. It says:

[image]

So the source here is the:

```
numbers.Where();
```

Since "**numbers**" variable is the IEnumerable of TSource.
TSource here is any IEnumerable of type "**T**" or any type of entity.

Now the last part is it accepts a Func. A Func is a predefined delegate type. It provides us a way to store anonymous methods in generalized and simple way. To further understand this, lets read it again. It says that it will **accept a source**, and **will output a boolean result**.

[image]

Now let's create a Func that accepts **TSource**, on this case, **integer** as our example and will **output boolean result**:

```
Func<int, bool> fncParameter = x => x % 2 == 0;
```

Now we can pass that into our:

```
numbers.Where
```

Which will be:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Func<int, bool> fncParameter = x => x % 2 == 0;
IEnumerable<int> result = numbers.Where(fncParameter);
```

Or in short:

```
ist<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
IEnumerable<int> result = numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: I think you're getting `OrderBy` and `Where` mixed up.

Comment: Would there be a chance of you explaining this a bit more ind etail over discord or something similar?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if it helps or if you have questions. @ChristofferNilsson

Comment: It makes more sense! Would be amazing if you would make an example with the line of code I posted above! Not going to ask you because you prbably have better things to do but if you have the time feel free to! I will mark this as an accepted answer!