# How do "Where" and "Select" work in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following snippet of code. I have few queries regarding the code snippet which I have mentioned after it.

```
var salaries = customerList
                    .Where(c => c.Age > 30)
                    .Select(c => c.Salary) // salary is of type long
                    .ToList();
```

- In above snippet of code, how does "Where" get access to the customerList and how does it define the type of "c"?
- Does "Where" return a temporary list of customers after applying the filter on which the Select acts?
- How exactly does "Select" know that it has to return only the "Salary"?
- How does the type of the variable "salaries" get set to List< long >?

Comment: Please check the `Where` signature.

Comment: This should help; https://stackoverflow.com/a/671425/1608418

Comment: read about lambda expressions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832337/interview-what-is-lambda-expression/3844487)

Comment: here you have article how linq works, and how it is translated [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671235/how-linq-works-internally)

Comment: I will advice reading Jon Skeet's series about [Reimplementing LinQ](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts/). The article for that question are : [REIMPLEMENTING LINQ TO OBJECTS: PART 2 – “WHERE”](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot/) and [REIMPLEMENTING LINQ TO OBJECTS: PART 3 – “SELECT” (AND A RENAME…)](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-3-quot-select-quot-and-a-rename/)

Comment: John Skeet's book: "C# in depth" helped me a lot in understanding LINQ and lambdas. There are a lot of examples and good advices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Where` is probably implemented like this (note that this is a very rough implementation, just do give you an idea of what it is like):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    foreach (T t in source) {
        if (predicate(t)) {
            yield return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `Where` is an extension method. You are essentially calling `Where(customerList, c => c.Age > 30)`. Now you should see where it gets access of the `customerList`. It also infers what `T` should be by looking at what kind of `IEnumerable` `customerList` is. Since it is a `IEnumerable<Customer>`, `T` is `Customer`, and so it expects a `Func<Customer, bool>` for the second argument. This is how it knows that `c` is `Customer`.

`Where` does not return a temporary list. A lot of LINQ methods make use of deferred evaluation. `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<Customer>` that is filtered. Remember that `IEnumerable` is just a sequence of things. This sequence returned by `Where` however, is not evaluated, until you ask for it. `Select` does the same as well. So a list is not created until you call `ToList`.

Your third question is kind of like asking "How does `Where` know how to filter" or "How does `Console.WriteLine` know how to write to the screen". That's what `Select` does. You can look at its implementation if you want. Here's a rough sketch:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> Select<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, U> mapping) {
    foreach (T t in source) {
        yield mapping(t);
    }
}
```

The type of the variable `salaries` is determined by looking at the method signatures of each of the methods you call. Your `Select` call returns a `IEnumerable<long>`, and `ToList`'s signature tells the compiler that, given a `IEnumerable<T>` it will return `List<T>`, so in this case, it returns a `List<long>`.

Answer (score 2):

Where clause exists in Enumerable class which uses for querying in .net framework. it provides as boolean condition and return source. It will convert to respective sql query eventually.

so your linq

```
var salaries = customerList
                    .Where(c => c.Age > 30)
                    .Select(c => c.Salary) // salary is of type long
                    .ToList();
```

old school sql command

```
SELECT [c].[Salary] FROM [CustomerList] WHERE [c].[Age] > '30'
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you understand lambda expressions better.
[Anatomy of the Lambda Expression](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-lambda-expression)

And this is for [Linq](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/what-is-linq)

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> how does "Where" get access to the customerList and how does it define
>   the type of "c"?

- customerList is of type List and `Where()` is an extension method of type List. So `Where()` method is accessible to customerList. `c => c.Age > 30` is a predicate define inside `Where()` clause. This predicate help list to filter out data based on condition. Here `c` indicates individual element present in List.

> How exactly does "Select" know that it has to return only the
>   "Salary"?

- Select is used to project individual element from List, in your case each `customer` from `customerList`. As Customer class contains property called Salary of type long, Select predicate will create new form of object which will contain only value of `Salary` property from `Customer` class.

> How does the type of the variable "salaries" get set to List< long >?

- `Select()` will crate new form with only Salary property something like

```
new {
      public long Salary{get; set;}
    }
```

.ToList() will convert `IEnumerable` returned by Select into `List`. Ultimately you will get `List<long>`

> "Where" return a temporary list of customers after applying the
>   filter on which the Select acts?

- Yes, Where will return filtered list(Precise `IEnumerable`)  on which you applied `Select()` method

I would suggest you to read [Linq in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/), [Where clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8), [Select method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8), [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1):

The [link  from @Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671235/how-linq-works-internally/671425#671425) can give a good idea.

Short answer is that LINQ is built on the compiler feature called Expressions. When you write something like `Where(c => c.Age > 18)` compiler doesn't actually compile the `c=> c.Age > 18` all the way like a regular method.

It builds a syntax tree that describes what that code does.

The `Where` function uses this to build a SQL query that is sent to the SQL server which executes that to get the results.

Suggest you look into the workings of [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netcore-3.0) and [`Expression<TDelegate>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=netcore-3.0) for more information.

Also helps to understand the [difference between IEnumerable and IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252785/975887).

Another example of Expressions used in other parts of C# like Razor pages that uses functions like [LabelFor(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) which uses the property you *express* to build a HTML label rather than executing the code.

HTH