# JavaScript: access variables inside anonymous function from the outside

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

Say I have this anonymous function:

```
(function(window){

 var private = 'private msg';

 function sayit() {
   alert(private) // works
 }

 document.body.onclick = sayit; // works

})(window);

// private shouldn't be accessible here
```

Is this how JavaScript should behave?

That is, there is no way to access `private` from anywhere outside of that anonymous function?

If so, is it possible to find some kind of hack to access `private` from the outside, leaving the code the way it is?

Comment: Not without changing the code.

Comment: private variables are meant to be private...why would you want to access a private variable from the outside?

Comment: @ rexcfnghk  - its not so much. its one of those moments where "thats just because thats how it works"

Comment: And why you need to do it? Just for fun?

Comment: @Damask - one may want to know if something can be done in order to guard against wrongly assuming it cannot be done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is how Javascript lets you have 'private' variables (hidden in a function scope).

No, there's no hack available to access variables such as `private` without re-writing the code.

Variables defined with `var` within a function can be accessed only from within that function.

Answer (score 10):

Ok. I got it.

```
(function(window){
    var alert_original = window.alert;
    window.alert = function(data) {
        window.extracted = data;
        alert_original(data);
    };
})(window);

(function(window){
    var private = 'private msg';
    function sayit() {
    alert(private) // works
 }
 document.body.onclick = sayit; // works
})(window);
```

After you click body, you can get 'private msg' from `extracted`

Comment: Clever. Only, you can't *change* the value of `private` so what you have is read-only 'access'.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't intended as "private" variables; that's just how closures work.  You can do the same thing in Perl and Python, at the very least, and probably a great many other languages with closures and lexical scoping.

Debuggers like Firebug or Chrome Inspector can still show you the entire stack at any point (including closed-over variables), but other than that and without changing the original code, I think you're out of luck.

Perhaps if you told us your actual problem...  :)

Comment: Does closure == anonymous function?

Comment: @barjonah - they are related but not the same. It is easy to form a closure with the declaration of an anonymous functions. A closure is formed when an anonymous  (or even a nested or regular named function)  refers to variables in it's parent scope. So an anonymous function is one way of creating a closure.

Comment: i can't help but feel i've [answered this before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/150185/17875)  :)  but Faiz is correct, yes.

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole point of having scope and private variables

Either

Set the private value to a global variable?

or

declare the variable outside

Answer (score -3):

You would have to do something like this:

```
var Test = (function(window){
 var private = 'private msg';
 var api = {};

 function sayit(){
   alert(private) // works
 }
 document.body.onclick = sayit; // works

api.sayit = sayit;
return api;
})(window);

Test.sayit(); //this would alert 'private msg'
```