# What does this javascript code mean?

Tags: javascript

```
var myval = (function(){})();
```

I don't understand `(function..)` meaning and even else code.

Comment: It's the syntax for an anonymous function in javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the role of the parentheses in the following piece of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938060/whats-the-role-of-the-parentheses-in-the-following-piece-of-code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you've got there is a:

**self-invoking anonymous function**

You're first creating a function-expression by having paranthesis around the function itself.
Just to write

```
function() {
}()
```

would not work in this instance, because this would define a function-declaration.

So after we have that, we can **call** itself by appending `()`

```
(function() {
})();
```

To verify that, try this:

```
var myval = (function(){return 'self executed!'})();

alert(myval); // === 'self executed'
```

Answer (score 8):

- `function(){}` — is a function expression, it defines a function
- `(function(){})` — wrapping it like this makes sure it gets treated as an expression
- `(function(){})()` — Adding `()` *calls* the function

And then the return value is assigned to a variable.

This is usually used to allow variables to be used without polluting the global scope.

Comment: `function(){}` will only be an expression in an assignment.

Comment: @jAndy, not only in an assignment, there are other contexts of *expression*, for example: `0,function(){}`, `new function(){}`, `foo(function(){})`, etc... The restriction on the grammar is at the level of the *ExpressionStatement*, it cannot start with either `{` or the token `function`. On *statement context* `function(){}` will be just a `SyntaxError` (no production of the grammar matches it).

Comment: @CMS: yes, I just wanted to clarfiy that just `function(){}` is not necessarily an expression. `+function(){}()` or `!function(){}()` will work also :-)

Answer (score 2):

This creates an anonymous function and immediately calls it. For example

```
(function ($) {
  // Original JavaScript code.
})(jQuery);
```

will allow you to use `$` in there and it equals `jQuery`.

Comment: +1 for common example -- I always start it as `;(function ...` though (because I write semi-colon free code and this is one case where ASI might not work as expected)

Answer (score 1):

This `function(){}` defines anonymous function <strike>(closure)</strike> with no body. By wrapping it in braces and adding empty parameters list at the end (`()`) you are running this closure. This is essentially equivalent to:

```
var f = function() {};
f();
```

Would this be easier to grasp?

```
(function(x, y, z){})(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Corrected, thx. Just to clarify - would it be enough to call this a closure if the function would use some local variables defined outside?

Comment: It's getting closer. It has to make reference to a local variable from an enclosing scope when executed _outside_ of that scope. Practically, this means that it has to be returned from a function and then executed in addition to it making reference to a local from an enclosing scope for it to be regarded as a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Related links:

- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
- http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg36/
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1482-A-Graphical-Explanation-Of-Javascript-Closures-In-A-jQuery-Context.htm

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze it piece by piece:

This define an anonymous function (i.e. a function with no name)

```
function(){}
```

Of course it would be more useful to put some instruction in between the `{}` brackets.

Now if you did

```
myval = function(){<something>};
```

You assign the function to myval (the function, NOT its return value!)

So then you could call `myval()` and it would be the same as calling the function itself.

Here instead you do call the function by putting `()` at the end. Therefore:

```
var myval = (function(){})();
```

calls the function, and puts the result (not the function itself this time) in `myval`