# What is this code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On some JS code on some sites I see Javascript code such as this:

```
SomeName.init = (function () {
    // some stuff
})();
```

I mean, this is not a jQuery plugin code such as this:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

    };
})( jQuery );
```

Then, what is it? and what is the resulting JS object?

Comment: I ... not sure what you're asking.  Both snippets demonstrate a function that is both declared and executed.  Beyond that, they don't seem related.

Comment: The 1st one is setting the results of an anonymous function into a variable named "init".  And as seen in the 2nd example, the anonymous function is a design-pattern often used in creating PLUG-IN's (or modules) and thus is often called the 'Module Pattern'.

Comment: [Here's what I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101638/what-does-this-javascript-code-mean) when I typed your title into the search box.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ I used search before posting my question, but there are really a lot of questions with this title. of course, they are not duplicates of each other but I didn't find the one you shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth). And those two snippets have more in common than you think.

Answer (score 8):

It's a anonymous function, which doesn't leak variables to the global scope when declaring variables using `var`.

```
SomeName.init = (function () {
    return 3.1415;
})();
```

`SomeName.init` is a number (3.1415), because `()` after the anonymous function declaration executes the function. There's no way to obtain the original function, unless defined within the anonymous function:

```
(function foo(){
    //foo refers to this function
    too = foo;
})();;
//foo is undefined
//too refers to the function, because `too` has been defined without var
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function () {
    // some stuff
})()
```

is a anonymous function that calls itself instantly. It's just a closure around the code inside to stop the variable scope becoming global.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the function returns.

```
(function() {
    //...
})();
```

Is used as a way to namespace code, or declare self-executing constructors. The resulting object is whatever that self-executing function returns.

The second snippet doesn't return anything and there is no `resulting JS object`.