# what does () do at the end of the following code?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the role of the parentheses in the following piece of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938060/whats-the-role-of-the-parentheses-in-the-following-piece-of-code)

```
var dummy = (function (name) {return name;}(dummy || {}));

dummy.foo = ( function(s){
    this.s = s;

    return true;
}) ();
```

ok so I am not familiar with OO javascript but I know a little bit. Am I correct to say that this is the constructor for foo? what does the () do at the very end? also why is function(s){} in parentesis as well? there was some code in between but I took them out for simplicity sake. Would the above be the same as the below?

```
dummy.foo = function(s){
    this.s = s;

    return true;
};
```

I am trying to see what some code someone else wrote does and I don't have much experience in OO side so I am so confused as what's what. I can't even figure out which is the constructor

Comment: Where are you getting these horrible examples from?

Comment: @Ben lol, looks like "yell and wink"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a self-executing JavaScript function:

http://briancrescimanno.com/2009/09/24/how-self-executing-anonymous-functions-work/

Answer (score 1):

```
var dummy = (function (name) {return name;}(dummy || {}));
```

This line passes the variable `dummy` to the function, and returns it exactly; otherwise, it passes an empty object to the function. (The function is evaluated on-the-spot.) The value is then stored in the variable `dummy`.

```
dummy.foo = ( function(s){
    this.s = s;

    return true;
}) ();
```

This defines the property `foo` to the object `dummy`. Currently, the function accepts an argument, which is stored to the property `s` of the object `dummy`. Currently, because it passes nothing to the function, it stores `undefined` to the property `s`.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis at the end call the function just defined.

Here `foo` is a function:

```
var foo = function (x) { return 2*x; };
```

Here `bar` is a number (4 to be precise):

```
var bar = function (x) { return 2*x; } (2);
```