# How to sort with lambda in Python

Tags: python, sorting, functional-programming, anonymous-function

I am trying to sort some values by attribute, like so:

```
a = sorted(a, lambda x: x.modified, reverse=True)
```

I get this error message:

```
<lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Why? How do I fix it?

---

<sub>This question was originally written for Python 2.x. In 3.x, the error message will be different: `TypeError: sorted expected 1 argument, got 2`.</sub>

Comment: add keywoard argument key = lambda x: x.modified will solve the problem

Answer (score 538, accepted):

Use

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x.modified, reverse=True)
#             ^^^^
```

On Python 2.x, the `sorted` function takes its arguments in this order:

```
sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False)
```

so without the `key=`, the function you pass in will be considered a `cmp` function which takes 2 arguments.

Comment: You have good chance to learn to appreciate keyword parameter passing from this experience.

Comment: This is very old but, do you have any idea why the error code is misleading? Your answer sounds like possible Python is supplying `lambda` with another parameter since a `cmp` function takes 2?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan the error is not misleading. `cmp`, a comparator function takes two arguments. If you don't specify that you are passing a `key`, it is assumed from the function parameters order that you are passing a comparator. Your lambda takes one parameter, therefore is not a valid comparator and that's what the error says.

Comment: Python 2 and 3 seem to have different function declarations. I use Python 3, so there is no cmp anymore. In Python2, it is an `iterable`, what is it in Python 3?

Answer (score 79):

```
lst = [('candy','30','100'), ('apple','10','200'), ('baby','20','300')]
lst.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
print(lst)
```

It will print as following:

```
[('apple', '10', '200'), ('baby', '20', '300'), ('candy', '30', '100')]
```

Comment: This does not work for string integers. Check this out! lst = [('999', '9'), ('303', '30'), ('343', '34')]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
print(lst)

Comment: The result is [('303', '30'), ('343', '34'), ('999', '9')] which is not sorted base on the second element in every list.

Comment: lst = [('candy','999','9'), ('apple','303','30'), ('baby','343','34')]
lst.sort(key=lambda x:x[2])
print(lst)

Comment: [('apple', '303', '30'), ('baby', '343', '34'), ('candy', '999', '9')]. Which is not sorted base on 2 element too!

Comment: @DanielKua That's pretty simple to fix. You can just do `int(x[1])` instead of just `x[1]`.

Answer (score 12):

You're trying to use key functions with lambda functions.

Python and other languages like C# or F# use [lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16501/5675325).

Also, when it comes to key functions and according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

> Both [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) and [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) have a key parameter to
> specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making
> comparisons.
>
> ...
>
> The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes. This technique is fast because the key function is called exactly once for each input record.

So, key functions have a parameter key and it can indeed receive a lambda function.

In [Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/) there's a nice example of its usage. Let's say you have the following list

```
ids = ['id1', 'id100', 'id2', 'id22', 'id3', 'id30']
```

and want to sort through its "integers". Then, you'd do something like

```
sorted_ids = sorted(ids, key=lambda x: int(x[2:])) # Integer sort
```

and printing it would give

```
['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id22', 'id30', 'id100']
```

In your particular case, you're only missing to write `key=` before lambda. So, you'd want to use the following

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x.modified, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at this Example, you will understand:

**Example 1:**

```
a = input()
a = sorted(a, key = lambda x:(len(x),x))
print(a)
```

input: `["tim", "bob", "anna", "steve", "john","aaaa"]`
output: `['bob', 'tim', 'aaaa', 'anna', 'john', 'steve']`

input: `["tim", "bob", "anna", "steve", "john","aaaaa"]`
output: `['bob', 'tim', 'anna', 'john', 'aaaaa', 'steve']`

---

**Example 2 (advanced):**

```
a = ["tim", "bob", "anna", "steve", "john","aaaaa","zzza"]
a = sorted(a, key = lambda x:(x[-1],len(x),x))
print(a)
```

output: `['anna', 'zzza', 'aaaaa', 'bob', 'steve', 'tim', 'john']`

---

**Example 3 (advanced):**

```
a = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,1],[1,6],[3,8],[4,9],[0,3],[2,6],[9,5]]
a = sorted(a, key = lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))
print(a)
```

output: `[[4, 9], [3, 8], [1, 6], [2, 6], [2, 5], [9, 5], [1, 4], [0, 3], [3, 1]]`

---

**Conclusion:**

`key = lambda x:(p1,p2,p3,p4,...,pn)`,
`x` is one element at a time from the stream of input.
`p1,p2,p3...pn` being properties based on which the stream of elements needs to be sorted.
based on priority order of `p1>p2>p3>...>pn`.
We can also add reverse=True, after the sorting condition, to sort the elements in reverse order.

Answer (score 8):

In Python3:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
def compare(i1,i2):
  return i1-i2
events.sort(key=cmp_to_key(compare))
```