# Can lambda be used instead of a method, as a key in sorted()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

This is my first time asking a question. I've already got so much help from you without even asking. (Gratitude face).
So, I found this useful piece of code from around here a few weeks ago.

```
import re

def yearly_sort(value):
    numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
    parts = numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts
```

It works perfectly here:

```
def get_files_sorted(path_to_dir):
   file_names = []
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_dir):
      for file_name in sorted(files, key=yearly_sort):
         file_names.append(os.path.join(root, file_name))
   return file_names
```

Now, I'm facing a problem describing the above function (as you can already see from a non-descriptive method name).

What should be the name of above method (instead of some_sort())?

Can this method be squeezed somehow in a lambda such that **key** in the sorted() can bind to key=lambda?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to replace it with a lambda? Do you understand how `lambda` works?

Comment: **Hello Community!**

Comment: Can you write function yearly_sort as lambda function, then yes

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams In my opinion its not suitable for a method. My team is really strict about _descriptive naming_ and I am unable to describe it properly. Yes I do understand how lambda works but, do not know enough for this one.

Comment: When coding guidelines induce programmers to jump through hoops (and make the code more cryptic) to evade adding a simple function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could squeeze it into a lambda provided that `numbers` is previously compiled (which increases performance)

```
numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
for file_name in sorted(files, key=lambda value : [int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0 for x in numbers.split(value)][1::2]):
```

In that case, we do an unnecessary test for items #0 and #3 onwards. Maybe it could be better, but that's the risk with complex lambdas: performance & lisibility can suffer.

Comment: for file_name in sorted(files, key=lambda name: [ int(numbers.split(name)[1]) ]):

Can this be used instead?

Comment: if it does the same (you never provided any input string), then yes!

Comment: Input string is like `"asdf_1234_asdf1234asdf.txt"`
yes it works a lot better now. Thanks :) @Jean

Answer (score 2):

It definitely can be `lambda` function. For example look at that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766633/how-to-sort-with-lambda-in-python).

But if you have complex function you should never move it to `lambda` because readability significantly decreases.

So here is [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Complex is better than complicated.