# how to sort files by ascending numbers in brackets

Tags: python, sorting, numbers, filenames

I'm new here and hope you can help me with my problem.

I have a list in python with foldernames like:

```
List = ['file_io(0).txt','file_io(1).txt',....,'file_io(13004).txt']
```

and I would like to sort these files by ascending numbers in the brackets.

If I use `sort(List)`, the files are sorted this way:

```
List = ['file_io(0).txt','file_io(1).txt','file_io(10).txt','file_io(100).txt',...]
```

Does anyone have an advice or a solution for me?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710/8014793

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to pull out the number from within the parentheses, convert that to `int`, then sort based on that numeric value.

```
>>> List = ['file_io(0).txt', 'file_io(1).txt', 'file_io(97).txt', 'file_io(100).txt', 'file_io(13004).txt']
>>> sorted(List, key=lambda i: int(re.match(r'file_io\((\d+)\).txt', i).group(1)))
['file_io(0).txt', 'file_io(1).txt', 'file_io(97).txt', 'file_io(100).txt', 'file_io(13004).txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are sure of the structure of your file naming, use this sort key to sort your list.

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[x.find("(")+1:x.find(")")]))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766633/how-to-sort-with-lambda-in-python