# Sorting a couple of lists together

Tags: python

I have 2 lists :  result, occurredtimes 
I want to sort them based on the occurredtimes

These are printed outputs of the lists :

```
    result is        ['3 - 1', '1 - 2', '0 - 0', '2 - 1', '2 - 3', '2 - 0' ...]
    occurredtimes is [322 , 423, 269, 643, 114, 565 ...]
```

The output I need is

```
    result           ['2 - 1', '2 - 0', '1 -2', '3 - 1', '0 - 0', '2 - 3' ...]
    occurredtimes    [643 , 565, 423, 322, 269, 114 ...]
```

I am trying to sort them but I cannot get what I need; I am sorry, I am sure it is an easy code

I tried as follows

```
    result, occurredtimes = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(result, occurredtimes))))
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself or are you asking generally how to sort a list?

Comment: Probably a better duplicate target: [Is it possible to sort two lists(which reference each other) in the exact same way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9764298/7851470)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
result, occurredtimes=zip(*sorted(zip(result, occurredtimes), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True))
```

Outputs:

```py
('2 - 1', '2 - 0', '1 - 2', '3 - 1', '0 - 0', '2 - 3')
(643, 565, 423, 322, 269, 114)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)() and pass an lambda function to sort them on the occurrence times.

```
In [9]: result = ['3 - 1', '1 - 2', '0 - 0', '2 - 1', '2 - 3', '2 - 0' ]

In [10]: ocurredtimes= [322 , 423, 269, 643, 114, 565]

In [11]: new_res=list( zip( result, ocurredtimes))


In [13]: new_res
Out[13]:
[('3 - 1', 322),
 ('1 - 2', 423),
 ('0 - 0', 269),
 ('2 - 1', 643),
 ('2 - 3', 114),
 ('2 - 0', 565)]


In [15]: sorted(new_res, key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True) #sorted OUTPUT 
Out[15]:
[('2 - 1', 643),
 ('2 - 0', 565),
 ('1 - 2', 423),
 ('3 - 1', 322),
 ('0 - 0', 269),
 ('2 - 3', 114)]
```

Also you can use the [sort](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort) function of list's and pass the same lambda function as parameter. That would do the job.

For more [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8966538/12210002) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3766633/12210002)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> result, occurredtimes = zip(*sorted(zip(result, occurredtimes), key = lambda i: i[1], reverse=True))
>>> result
('2 - 1', '2 - 0', '1 - 2', '3 - 1', '0 - 0', '2 - 3')
>>> occurredtimes
(643, 565, 423, 322, 269, 114)
```

The way this works is you can essentially `zip` the lists together element-wise. Then you can sort by the `[1]` element which is from `occurredtimes`, and use `reverse=True` to sort descending.

```
>>> sorted(zip(result, occurredtimes), key = lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
[('2 - 1', 643), ('2 - 0', 565), ('1 - 2', 423), ('3 - 1', 322), ('0 - 0', 269), ('2 - 3', 114)]
```

The last `zip(*sorted(` is to unpack the sorted tuples back into two separate lists again.

Answer (score 0):

You can first combine the two list into one list and then sort based on the criteria you need. The code will look like this:

```
result = ['3 - 1', '1 - 2', '0 - 0', '2 - 1', '2 - 3', '2 - 0']
occurredtimes = [322 , 423, 269, 643, 114, 565]
new_list=[]
for i in range(len(result)):
    new_list.append([occurredtimes[i],result[I]])   
new_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=True)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) of numpy. It's faster and less code:

```
O = np.array([322 , 423, 269, 643, 114, 565])
values = np.array(['3 - 1', '1 - 2', '0 - 0', '2 - 1', '2 - 3', '2 - 0'])
arr = np.argsort(O)[::-1]
print(values[arr])
```

Output:

```
array(['2 - 1', '2 - 0', '1 - 2', '3 - 1', '0 - 0', '2 - 3'], dtype='<U5')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
occurredtimes = np.argsort(occurredtimes)[::-1]

print("result:", [ result[i] for i in occurredtimes ])
print("occuredtimes:", occurredtimes)
```