# How can I sort strings in a list based on the integer within each item?

Tags: python, list

I have the following list, which was created from a file:
`scores=["bob.21","jeff.46","michael.75","david.12"]` 
How can I sort items of this list based on the integer within each item?

Comment: (Dupe of) [How to sort with lambda in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766633/how-to-sort-with-lambda-in-python) + some string parsing

Comment: It does, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `key` function that parses out the integer:

```
scores.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.partition('.')[2]))
```

That just logically sorts it as if the values were `[21, 46, 75, 12]` while preserving the original values.

Comment: @timgeb: Not when they're all two digits long (though it's harmless to convert, and might make the comparisons infinitesimally faster). But it's absolutely necessary if there might be a different number of digits. `20 < 3` is false, but `'20' < '3'` is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = ["bob.21","jeff.46","michael.75","david.12"]

sorted_scores = sorted(scores,key=lambda s: int(s.split('.')[1]))
print(sorted_scores)
```

output

```
['david.12', 'bob.21', 'jeff.46', 'michael.75']
```