# How to sort a list by the number of items in another list that is inside dict, with keys similar to the first list

Tags: python

how to sort a list by the number of elements of another list that is inside dict (Keys of dict are similar with elements of list that should be sorted) .

This is the list I want to sort: `list_to_sort = ['a','b','c','d']`
This is a dict with the elements: `reference_dict = {'a':[1,0,0,1,0], 'b':[1,0,0,0,1,1], 'c':[1,1,1,1,0], 'd':[1,0,0,0,0]}`

I should get `list_after_sort = ['d','a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 2):

Using `key` in a `sorted` function gives an ability to pass a function by which the elements would be sorted.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766633/how-to-sort-with-lambda-in-python) covers useful information.

You can use:

```
list_to_sort = ['a','b','c','d']
reference_dict = {'a':[1,0,0,1,0], 'b':[1,0,0,0,1,1], 'c':[1,1,1,1,0], 'd':[1,0,0,0,0]}
sorted(list_to_sort, key = lambda x: sum(reference_dict[x]))

# ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: But if instead of [1,1,0,0,0,0] there is ['element', 'element, None, None, None]. What to do in this case ?

Comment: replace the key by `key = lambda x: sum([e is not None for e in reference_dict[x]])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` parameter of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) to pass an arbitrary function.

In this case, get the values from the dictionary and `sum` them:

```
list_after_sort = sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda x: sum(reference_dict[x]))
```

output: `['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']`

###### using truthy values:

```
reference_dict = {'a':[1,0,0,'X',0],
                  'b':[1,0,0,0,1,1],
                  'c':[1,1,1,1,0],
                  'd':['element', 'element', None, None, None]}

sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda x: sum(map(bool, reference_dict[x])))
# ['a', 'd', 'b', 'c']
```

###### using blacklist of objects

```
blacklist = set([0, None, 'None'])

sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda x: sum(e not in blacklist
                                       for e in reference_dict[x]))
```

Comment: But if instead of `[1,1,0,0,0,0]` there is `['element', 'element, None, None, None]`.
What to do in this case ?

Comment: @SOmething you can convert to booleans to benefit from the truthy values (see update), please make the exact use case more explicit in defining exactly what should be counted and what shouldn't

Comment: But if None is write like 'None' ?

Comment: @SOmething that's why you need to come up with an explicit logic of what should count or not. Can you elaborate in your case?

Comment: I need to count all elements that aren't 'None'.
I don't think I can elaborate

Comment: @SOmething check the update, then you should have the logic