# display text when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I need to have a row of text display when a checkboxed is checked.  I know this is pretty simple, but I am new to this and when I try to read other answers to this question I get lost.

this is what I have:

```
 function RiskPlanRqd()
  {
    $('#RiskMgmt').click(function()
    {
        if ($("#RiskMgmt").is(':checked')) 
        {
            $(".togglevisibility").show();
        } 
        else 
        {   
            $(".togglevisibility").hide();
        }
    }       )
  }
```

Then for the checkbox I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="RiskMgmt" />Risk Management Plan<br />
```

and for the text I want to show up if checked i have:

```
<td> <id="PlanStatus"; class="togglevisibility">Plan Status: </td>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to show the HTML. I *also* properly closed the opening `<td>` tag (adding the `>` character). If this is omitted you have invalid HTML, so I'm *assuming* it was a typo. If *not* then your problem is invalid HTML, and you should roll the question back. Also you're missing the `=` characters to assign a value to the attributes in your `input` HTML tag, which makes *that* invalid HTML as well.

Comment: @DavidThomas still looking for help if you can provide any insight on what is shown above

Answer (score 4):

### Quick fix...

**You *could* fix this in place by fixing a typo and a value check...**

`if ($("#RiskMgmtPlan").val() == '1')` should be `if ($("#RiskMgmt").is(':checked')`

Also `Function` should be `function`.

You also typo'd the ID declaration on the checkbox.

**But, you can do this with a lambda...**

```
$('#RiskMgmt').click(function(){
    if ($("#RiskMgmt").is(':checked')) {
        $("#PlanStatus").show();
        $("#CreatePlan").show();
        $("#NotStarted").show();
    } else {
        $("#PlanStatus").hide();
        $("#CreatePlan").hide();
        $("#NotStarted").hide();
    }
});
```

**And, you can remove 4 lines of code by assigning classes...**

Add `class='togglevisibility'` to your three elements you want to show & hide, then change the above to this:

```
$('#RiskMgmt').click(function(){
    if ($("#RiskMgmt").is(':checked')) {
        $(".togglevisibility").show();
    } else {
        $(".togglevisibility").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: and the checkbox should be...... <input type="checkbox" id"RiskMgmt" onclick="RiskPlanRQD();"/>Risk Management Plan<br />

Comment: @Dani You need an `=` between `id` and `"RiskMgmt"`. If it were up to me I'd remove the `onClick='RiskPlanRQD();'` and use the 3rd option suggested.

Comment: then the initial function should be: function RiskPlanRqd()
   {
     if ($("#RiskMgmtPlan").is(':checked') {
        $("#PlanStatus").show();
        $("#CreatePlan").show();
        $("#NotStarted").show();
    } else {
        $("#PlanStatus").hide();
        $("#CreatePlan").hide();
        $("#NotStarted").hide();
    }

Comment: @Dani Change `$("RiskMgmtPlan").is(":checked")` to `$("RiskMgmt").is(":checked")`. Right now your function is looking for an element with ID `RiskMgmtPlan` but your checkbox is called `RiskMgmt`.

Comment: You really should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.click()`: `$(document).on('click', '#RiskMgmt', function() {`

Comment: @John `.click(handler)` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/)) is a shorthand for `.on('click', handler)`. There is absolutely no difference in function but `.click` is more readable. And no, you should NOT bind an event to `document` instead of a specific DOM element.

Comment: @LightningDust Welp, learn something new, thanks for pointing that out. My fault for not reading more before I commented!

Comment: function RiskPlanRqd()
   {
  $('#RiskMgmt').click(function()
   {if ($("#RiskMgmt").is(':checked')) 
  {$(".togglevisibility").show();
  } 
   else {$(".togglevisibility").hide();}
   }
  )}

Comment: @Dani - You don't need that to be within a function. It is a handler with a bound [lambda function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function). You can use the exact code I wrote in the 3rd example as long as you've put `class='togglevisibility'` on the elements you wish to toggle.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified version.. Bind the event, then toggle visibility based on the checkbox state.

```
$('#RiskMgmt').change(function(e) {
    $("#PlanStatus, #CreatePlan, #NotStarted").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#RiskMgmt').bind('click',RiskPlanRqd);
});
```

Should work.

Alternatively:

```
<input type="checkbox" value "1" id="RiskMgmt" onclick="RiskPlanRqd();" />Risk Management Plan<br />
```

Should also work.

Comment: -1: Not sure how you got upvotes, you've failed to spot that his function as written is broken. All you've helped him do is bind a broken function to a click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#RiskMgmt').click(function(){
  if (this.checked) 
  {
    $("#PlanStatus").show();
    $("#NotStarted").show();    
  }
});
```

It shouldnt be harder then this, if the checkbox is checked, display whatever you want.