# Can I utilize Pyside clicked.connect to connect a function which has a parameter

Tags: python, function, pyside, qpushbutton, click

I want to have a function in main class which has parameters not only  self.

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def clearTextEdit(self, x):
            self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(" ")
            print("Script in Textbox is Cleaned!",)
```

x will be my additional parameter and I want clearTextEdit to be called by click.

```
self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.clearTextEdit(x))
```

it does not allow me to write x as parameter in clicked. Can you help me!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Solution

This is a perfect place to use a lambda:

```
self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clearTextEdit(x))
```

Remember, `connect` expects a function of no arguments, so we have to wrap up the function call in another function.

### Explanation

Your original statement

```
self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.clearTextEdit(x))  # Incorrect
```

was actually *calling* `self.clearTextEdit(x)` when you made the call to `connect`, and then you got an error because `clearTextEdit` doesn't return a function of no arguments, which is what `connect` wanted.

### Lambda?

Instead, by passing `lambda: self.clearTextEdit(x)`, we give `connect` a function of no arguments, which when called, will call `self.clearTextEdit(x)`. The code above is equivalent to

```
def callback():
    return self.clearTextEdit(x)
self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(callback)
```

But with a lambda, we don't have to name "callback", we just pass it in directly.

If you want to know more about lambda functions, you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function) for more detail.

---

On an unrelated note, I notice that you don't use `x` anywhere in `clearTextEdit`. Is it necessary for `clearTextEdit` to take an argument in the first place?

Comment: thank you Istvan, you made my code more readable and less complex:) Let me ask you one more questıon: what if I have another function and I want to add that function as a parameter in my original function. such as:
def myFunct():
    return x

and
self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda:self.clearTextEdit(clearTextEdit(myFunct)))
is it allowed in pyside?? Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, I just needed an example so that I could do in my project. writing whole script would be garbage I guess. I would thank u a lot. my duty is done :)

Comment: @mesutali Yes, that can be done in the same way as passing any other argument. Your example would look something like `self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clearTextEdit(myFunct))` (you had an extra `clearTextEdit`)