# How to determine which button is pressed out of Button grid in Python TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a GUI with Python TKinter where I have a grid of some 24 buttons which I have created using a loop (not individually). Is there any way in which I can get the Text of the button that I pressed.

Since it is in loop, a callback function even with lambda is not helping me. I don't wish to write separate code for, what happens when each different button is pressed. I just need to know the text of the corresponding button so that I could initiate another generic function which works with that text only.

ps: I am able to do the same task but with List and curselection() and don't want it this way.

```
self.num = 11

for r in range(0,5):

   for c in range(0,3):

       R = r; C = c

       resNum = "Ch0"+str(self.num);

       self.button1_rex = tk.Button(self.frame, text = resNum,font=("Helvetica", 14), justify = CENTER,width = 20, command = self.new_window)

       self.button1_rex.grid(row=R, column=C, sticky=W)

       self.num = self.num+1
```

self.new_window is the function that opens a new window and needs to do other functionalities based on the button number (like "Ch011" etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is just to, when you are constructing the button, bind the name to the command, either using `functools.partial` or a `lambda`.

Using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
self.button1_rex = tk.Button(..., command=functools.partial(self.new_window, resNum))
```

Using a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
self.button1_rex = tk.Button(..., command=lambda r=resNum: self.new_window(r))
```

For more infomation about the lambda, see [What is a lambda (function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16501/3946766) and [Python tkinter creating buttons ... arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865170/3946766).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

I already tried with lambda, its not serving the purpose as it always returns the last value of "resNum" and not the currently selected value.

However, your first suggestion of using "partial" has worked for me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, its causing syntax error. 

I'm sorry for inconvenience. I don't have much experience in python.

Comment: AH, that's true. I'm too used to python 3 and Qt ATM. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Its working correctly.
Can you please direct me to some tutorial/help on the usage of "lambda". 
It would be great if you could just explain the "lambda" approach used here.

Comment: I've added some SO links, and maybe something like http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html helps?