# What does "$this->array[]()" mean?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am not able to understand the code, that is something like :- 
`$this->array[$key]($parameter)`

Why is there `($parameter)` after `$this->array[$key]` ?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reference, the code snippet being referred to here is the following one-line function:

```
/**
 * Call a custom driver creator.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  array  $config
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function callCustomCreator($name, array $config)
{
    return $this->customCreators[$config['driver']]($this->app, $name, $config);
}
```

The value being held at the location denoted by `$this->customCreators[$config['driver']]` in that code snippet is a `function`.  You normally call a named function like this:

```
functionName();
```

The open/close parentheses tells PHP to *call/execute that function* rather than just *reference* it, meaning you can pass that function around to a separate function as a *parameter* like this:

```
anotherFunction($this->customCreators[$config['driver']]);

function anotherFunction($creatorFn) {
    $creatorFn();
}
```

PHP [added support](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for [lambda-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function) functions (PHP uses the term 'anonymous') in version 5.3, which is when you can say we started treating functions as [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

Answer (score 5):

In the code you referenced, the array contains a function which gets called with the specified parameters. It's just a regular function call, but the function (or rather a reference to it) is stored in the array.

Comment: Technically, the example OP provided wouldn't actually work, as `[]` is used solely for pushing elements onto the array.

Comment: Yeah, the code line he posted in the question wouldn't work. I was referring to the GitHub link he posted.