# Meaning of java operator "->"

Tags: java

What is the meaning of the java operator "->" like in the following code, taken from the initialization of a SpringBoot application:

```
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

        return (container -> {
            ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/401.html");
            ErrorPage error403Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "/403.html");
            ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404.html");
            ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500.html");

            container.addErrorPages(error401Page, error403Page, error404Page, error500Page);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), a language feature first introduced in Java 8.  Basically this is an inline anonymous function that takes `container` as a parameter.  Usually lambdas return values but here it looks like it is just carrying out the "side effect" of calling `addErrorPages` to `container`.  There is no type specified for `container` as Java intuits it from the context.

Lambda expressions are more than a language feature, they are also a whole area of computer science and functional programming.  A good SO post describing them is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function).