# Argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a problem with my PyQt button action. I would like to send a String with the Function but I got this Error:

> TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
cocktail = loadUi('create.ui')

def mixCocktail(str):
      cocktail.show()
      cocktail.showFullScreen()
      cocktail.lbl_header.setText(str)


widget = loadUi('drinkmixer.ui')

widget.btn_ckt1.clicked.connect(mixCocktail("string"))

widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What line is this error showing up on?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "------\drinkmixer.py", line 27, in <module>
    widget.btn_ckt1.clicked.connect(mixCocktail("string"))
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Comment: Ah. That's because you aren't returning anything from `mixCocktail()`.

Comment: From looking at some example online, it looks like it expects a callable function. In which case you should replace that argument with `lambda: micCocktail("string")`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works

Comment: If you ever need to do that with a multi-arguments function, lambda won't work but you can use the `partial` library and connect your signal and function like so: `.connect(partial(my_function, arg1=..., arg2=...))`

Answer (score 26):

As suggested by [user3030010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030010/user3030010) and [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) it expects a callable function. In which case you should replace that argument with `lambda: mixCocktail("string")`
**AND ALSO** don't use `str` it's a python built-in datatype I have replaced it with `_str`

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
cocktail = loadUi('create.ui')

def mixCocktail(_str):
      cocktail.show()
      cocktail.showFullScreen()
      cocktail.lbl_header.setText(_str)
      

widget = loadUi('drinkmixer.ui')

widget.btn_ckt1.clicked.connect(lambda: mixCocktail("string"))

widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

More about lambda functions: [What is a lambda (function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/16509#16509)

Comment: `str` is not a keyword - it's a built-in type.

Comment: Thanks for rectifying, I knew I was writing something wrong.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. The correct solution was given in the [comment by user3030010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982518/argument-1-has-unexpected-type-nonetype#comment69174849_40982518).

Comment: @ekhumoro rectified.

Comment: made it wiki as it was from both of your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

instead of this

> widget.btn_ckt1.clicked.connect(mixCocktail("string"))

write

> widget.btn_ckt1.clicked.connect(lambda:mixCocktail("string"))