# What's the exact difference between lambda and normal function?

Tags: javascript, lambda

Previously, I learned lambda as shorten way to make instance of function(I learned from C# book), but when I used lambda with Vue.js, I encountered a problem.
This works well:

```
mounted: function(){ (...)
```

But this not works:

```
mounted: () => { (...) }
```

I want to get perfect explanation for this.

Comment: The context of `this` is saved using arrow functions. I wouldn't be surprised that the this context is wrong at time of declaration, but having only 1 function it's hard to say

Comment: Also to clear the confusion: What is a lambda function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function

Comment: See the note about arrow functions: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: Don't try to infer anything from C# to JS. Despite the syntactic similarity to lambdas, arrow functions are just one syntax amongst many for creating inline functions in JS.