# How can i compare and print an element from a 2D list in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, max, min

I have this 2D list where the first element is the name of company the second is how much a senior developer gets salary and the third element is how many hours they work/week.

```
brands = [["Microsoft", "120", "38", "1124"], ["Apple", "150", "40", "1800"], ["Google", "110", "35", "1437"]]
```

I am trying to compare `brands[0][1] with brand[1][1] and brands [2][1]` and print the lowest and highest wages in industry e.g `"The lowest wage: Google, 110" "The highest wage: Apple,150"`, then printing lowest and highest working hours, for a short list it is ease with if and else statements but i am trying to make a general loop for in case of a much larger list.

I tried min() but it was unsuccessfully, i am sure there is a way to make it work though.

Comment: You should definitely be putting these into a class. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: This is for learning purpose and it we are not allowed to use classes, nor import statistics nor zip

Comment: You can find the minimum wage with `min(brand[1] for brand in brands)`, but due to your choice of data structure, there's no similarly easy way to also find the corresponding company name.

Comment: @JohnGordon That is very false. `min(brands, key=lambda x:int(x[1]))[0]`

Comment: @mypetlion Very nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
wage=[]
for var in range(len(brands)):
   wage.append(brands[var][1])

min=wage.index(min(wage))
print("The lowest wage :{0}, {1}".format(brands[min][0],brands[min][1])
```

Comment: This works too, this was my initial idea to collect the values in a new list and then print the lowest value with min() method but did not know how, because i am in early beginning in coding. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would sort your list, then take the first and last element. You can put it in an `f-string` for printing (if using python 3.6 or above):

```
sorted_brands = sorted(brands, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))

print(f'the lowest wage: {sorted_brands[0][0]}, {sorted_brands[0][1]}, the highest wage: {sorted_brands[-1][0]}, {sorted_brands[-1][1]}')
#'the lowest wage: Google, 110, the highest wage: Apple, 150'
```

Comment: What does `key=lambda and x:int(x[1])` do, if you can explain?

Comment: It says: sort the lists by the value of `x[1]`, cast as an integer. `x` is an anonymous variable (you can read about [lambda functions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16501/6671176))

Answer (score 1):

You can *sort* with *lambda* by the desired category `key=lambda x: x[1]`, would refer to wages, Then print the corresponding indices, of the `list[0][0], list[0][x]` for our low and `list[-1][0], list[-1][x]` for our highs

```
wage = sorted(brands, key=lambda x: x[1])
print('The lowest wage: {}, {}'.format(wage[0][0], wage[0][1]))
print('The highest wage: {}, {}'.format(wage[-1][0], wage[-1][1]))

hours = (sorted(brands, key=lambda x: x[2]))
print('The lowest working hours: {}, {}'.format(hours[0][0], hours[0][2]))
print('The highest working hours: {}, {}'.format(hours[-1][0], hours[-1][2]))
```

> ```
> The lowest wage: Google, 110
> The highest wage: Apple, 150
> The lowest working hours: Google, 35
> The highest working hours: Apple, 40
> ```

Comment: Thanks man, @sacul did exactly the same thing. But i will save this code for the next project because this time i am not allowed to lambda, however i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
company = None
minwage = None

for brand in brands:
    if minwage is None or brand[1] < minwage:
        minwage = brand[1]
        company = brand[0]

print 'Lowest wage was: %s,%s' % (minwage, company)
```