# How are lambda functions useful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda

Currently I am learning `lambda` functions in Python 3.
Till now all I know about `lambda` functions is that its an anonymous function which can take any number of arguments but can contain only one expression.

So my question is that why do we need `lambda` functions if we can do the same using normal expression. I mean what was the actual purpose of introducing `lambda` functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function?rq=1

Comment: There's no such thing as a lambda function. A lambda *expression* is one way to create a `function` object.

Comment: Python 3 almost didn't have lambda expressions. Things like `operator.itemgetter` were intended as replacements for the major use cases, and as you've noticed, there's nothing you can define with a lambda expression that you can't define with a `def` statement as well. In the end, they were retained, though.

Answer (score 1):

Occassionally you need a very simple function for a one-time use, e.g. to pass as a paramater to `.sort()` to tell it how to do the sorting. E.g. if you want to sort a list of tuples on their second element,

```
list_of_tuples.sort(key=lambda t: t[1])
```

is nicely concise, compared to

```
def first_element(t):
    return t[1]

list_of_tuples(key=first_element)
```

And that is all.

Answer (score 0):

i rarely use random functions, but i dislike to introduce a named function just to use as the `key` in `sort`. i prefer

```
lst = (('s', 5), ('b', 2), ('h', 3))
srt = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

to

```
def sort_by(x):
    return x[1]

srt = sorted(lst, key=sort_by)
```