# What does arrow do in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm starting developing for Android using Kotlin. I have a problem with some concepts.
I use "->" in a condition statement but I don't know what that means in this example:

```
 XmlPullParser.START_TAG -> {...}
 XmlPullParser.TEXT -> textValue = xpp.text
 XmlPullParser.END_TAG -> {...}
```

All the code is:

```
        val factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
        factory.isNamespaceAware = true
        val xpp = factory.newPullParser()
        xpp.setInput(xmlData.reader())
        var eventType = xpp.eventType
        var currentRecord = FeedEntry()
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            val tagName = xpp.name.toLowerCase()    
            when (eventType) {

              XmlPullParser.START_TAG -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "parse: Starting tag for " + tagName)
                    if (tagName == "entry") {
                        inEntry = true
                    }
                }

                XmlPullParser.TEXT -> textValue = xpp.text

                   XmlPullParser.END_TAG -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "parse: Ending tag for " + tagName)
                    if (inEntry) {
                        when (tagName) {
                            "entry" -> {
                                applications.add(currentRecord)
                                inEntry = false
                                currentRecord = FeedEntry()  
                            }

                            "name" -> currentRecord.name = textValue
                            "artist" -> currentRecord.artist = textValue
                            "releasedate" -> currentRecord.releaseDate = textValue
                            "summary" -> currentRecord.summary = textValue
                            "image" -> currentRecord.imageURL = textValue
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a lambda (function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function)

Comment: Both comments here are simply not true. He is asking about the `when` expression. Not about something related to a lambda!

Answer (score 6):

This is just the [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax) for a Kotlin [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression).

Basically, it checks the condition inside the `when ()` and executes the block after `->` if it matches.
You can either "inline" the code which has to be executed **or** wrap it into curly brackets.

See also [this example (Kotlin Playground)](https://pl.kotl.in/03lRI3SZp) and change the `aString` to another value.

Comment: yes your right. I studied about "When()" with "is ... ->". as I understand they are the same without "is".

Comment: You have to use the `is` keyword if you want to check the type of a instance. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Comment: ok thanks. I have another question . when we enter to "when" block and for example first statement like : "XmlPullParser.START_TAG ->{} " is true . at this time does it break from "when block" or continue with next statements until end?

Comment: It does not fall through like the Java [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). So it will break for the first condition it matches. 
I've linked the `when` documentation in the post. Please read it 