# What exactly does this code do to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Hey guys I was wondering what exactly this code does, how does it iterate through the `dataframe` and what exactly does the lambda function do?

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above block of code traverses the data frame column-wise and drops NA values. Lambda functions are the anonymous functions that are well explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function) text.

Comment: got that, thanks! 
What exactly is the purpose of the ".values" behind the dropna()?

Comment: The ".values" is used to cast in the datatypes to accommodate the variability such as in case of  dtypes that are float16 and float32, dtype will be upcast to float32, etc.