# Tkinter: Radiobutton forground color when selected

Tags: python, tkinter

I have `Radiobutton` displayed in sunken button look that I would like to have:

- black text on white background when not selected,
- white text on dark gray background when selected.

Currently I only have gray background but no white text when selected, which makes for poor contrast.

[image]

```
for (lbl, val) in [("A", "a"), ("B", "b"))]:
    rb = tk.Radiobutton(tab,
                        text=lbl,
                        variable=v,
                        value=val,
                        command=select,
                        selectcolor=gray,
                        indicatoron=0,
                        width=25, pady=7.5)
    rb.pack(...)
```

`tk.Radiobutton` has an option to configure `selectcolor`, which is the background color when selected, but it seems to offer no such option for the foreground color when selected.

I thought that one might achieve this by specifying a `command` triggered on selection that will `rb.config` the `foreground` on that radiobutton which is selected, but this would require accessing externally the properties of radio buttons themselves, rather than just the value of the variable they set, which I found no way to do so far.

How do I achieve an option along the lines of `selectforeground`?

Comment: wouldnt `rb.config(foreground='white')` this work?

Comment: @Cool Cloud No, because I only what white text for whichever button is selected, not all of them.

Comment: oh, you have more than one.

Comment: Yes, the code snippet in my first version of the post was too heavily simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [annonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314) for this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def select(rb):
    rb.config(foreground='white')
    for rb_ in rbs:
        if rb_ != rb:
           rb_.config(fg='black')

root = tk.Tk()

rbs=[]

def do_buttons():
    for _ in range(11):
        v=tk.IntVar()
        val = 1

        rb = tk.Radiobutton(root,
                            text="A",
                            variable=v,
                            value=val,
                            selectcolor='gray',
                            indicatoron=0,
                            width=25, pady=7.5)
        rb.config(command=lambda arg=rb:select(arg))

        rb.pack()
        rbs.append(rb)

b = tk.Button(root, text='click', command=do_buttons)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry, I was including a too simplified version of my actual code; see the update. My problem is that I have several radio buttons (so there is no one `rb`) and I can not find a way to access which exact button is the one selected and to be configured.

Comment: @lemontree updated my answer, let me know if something missing or you have questions about.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense. I had tried out something similar, but specified the command already upon instantiation and ran into the problem that I obviously could not use the `rb` variable which was just being defined, and failed to see that I could simply `config` `rb` after the initial assignment. This works. Thank you!

Comment: I modified your `select` funcion such that additionally, all other radio buttons that are now no longer selected are changed back to `fg=black`: Save every `rb` into a list `rbs` upon creation, then in `select`, add `for rb_ in rbs: if rb_ != rb: rb_.config(fg=black)`.

Comment: Is this how you would edit it? Or could you edit it by yourself? I would accept it.

Comment: Yes, that's it; perfect.