# How to deal with "AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'messagebox'"?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, messagebox

I'm studying about 'tkinter' recently.
Pycharm told me here is no 'messagebox', but 'messagebox.py' does exist in my 'tkinter'.
Many ways I gained from Internet can't solve this.
Please help me, I'll appreciate for that.

```
greet_button = Button(
    table,
    text = 'Yes',
    width = 20,
    height = 2,
    bg = 'yellow',
    fg = 'red',
    command = table.messagebox.showinfo(title='Hello', message='Hello!')
)
```

Comment: Did you import `from tkinter import messagebox `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some packages of tkinter need a extra import like ttk, ttkthemes or messagebox.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
def err():
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title='hello', message='hello')

erro = tk.Button(root, text="Top", command=err)
erro.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

As oneliner you would need an [annonymus function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()

erro = tk.Button(root, text="Top", command=lambda:tk.messagebox.showinfo(title='hello', message='hello'))
erro.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ummm...isnt `themedtk` part of `ttkthemes` ? and not `tkinter` directly?

Comment: I had the `python AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute` error not about a messagebox, but something else. I cannot trace it back anymore, but I know that importing `ttk` or anything else did not help. I think it was rather a problem of the order and indentation, or somehow linked to [Either Enter or button trigger "TypeError ... missing 1 required positional argument" or "TypeError ... takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276569/11154841).

Comment: @questionto42 what attribute is missing? Based on the context you provided I guess it is missing attribute "tk" and you have done something wrong by subclassing a widget. [You can join the tkinter chat on stackoverflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249491/tkinter)