# How to pass an argument through a function using lambda

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

For an equalizer that is part of a bigger GUI,

[image]

I made a FOR loop to accommodate all the different scales. I would like to pass the 'freq' value during each function call.

```
# Frequencies to equalize
freq=['100','250','500','1000','2000','3000','4000','5000','6000','8000']

yval=0
for  index, value in enumerate(freq):
    # Freq (Hz)
    yval=yval+1
    xval=1
    self.create_label(EQframe,xval,yval,value+' Hz')
    # yval=yval
    xval=2
    # self.create_scale(Oliveframe,xval,yval,32,512,32,"vertical",128)
    self.create_EQ_scale(EQframe,xval,yval,0.5,-0.5,0.1,"vertical",0,100,'Red',value,self.eq_coeff)
```

Therefore when the user changes the scale, i want to be able to save the adjusted scale data in a global variable for the corresponding 'freq'.

```
def create_EQ_scale(self,parent,xval,yval,start,end,resolution,orient,default,lng,clr,ch_no,cmdtrig):
    OHAEQ_scale = tk.Scale(parent,resolution=resolution, from_=start, to=end, orient=orient,length=lng,fg=clr,command=lambda ch_no: cmdtrig(ch_no))
    OHAEQ_scale.grid(row=xval, column=yval, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S, padx=20, pady=4)
    OHAEQ_scale.set(default)
```

In order to test the function , I wrote the following

```
def eq_coeff(self, ch_no):
    print(ch_no)
```

The function gets called like i want it to. I was hoping it would print the 'freq' value based on which scale i adjusted, but it rather shows the actual value of the scale, i.e 0.1 or 0.2 rather than the freq value. I know its probably something simple, but i can't quite figure out what i have done wrong. :(

[image]

Comment: Try `lambda ch_no=ch_no: cmdtrig(ch_no)` ?

Comment: Try `lambda v: cmdtrig(ch_no, v)` and `def eq_coeff(self, ch_no, value)`.

Comment: If you intressted in how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314

Comment: @Atlas435 ofcourse, im interested. Thank you.