# How to make a Treeview column header into a Button?

Tags: python, sorting, button, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to improve the functionality of my GUI by adding buttons to the headings but can't find any examples or  information on this one. Is there a way to make the headings into a clickable button in this example? The `Treeview` is going to be populated from a DB so, if I can get the buttons to work, it means I can order the display in a nicer way than having more buttons outside the "box".

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

screen = tk.Tk() 
screen.title('This One')
screen.geometry('890x400')
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("clam")
screen.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
screen.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

cols = ('TOKEN', 'F-500', 'F-250', 'F-100', 'F-24', 'POS','NEG')
box = ttk.Treeview(screen, columns=cols, show='headings')
for col in cols:
    box.heading(col, text=col)
    box.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky='nsew')


box.column("TOKEN", width=95)
box.column("F-500", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-250", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-100", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-24", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("POS", width=75, anchor='center')
box.column("NEG", width=75, anchor='center')



closeButton = tk.Button(screen, text="Close", width=15, command=exit).grid(row=10, column=0)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: is `box.heading(col, text=col, command= lambda:print('hi'))` what you are asking for?

Comment: For how lambda works follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314

Comment: That is a start! that gives all the heading "buttons" a function but how would I get each one to have a seperate function? for example print("hi") when "token is clicked but print("bye") when f-500 is clicked...

Comment: @Monty2 see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heading od the Treeview already are *buttons* with the optional keyword `command`. To use this in a forloop you can use `lambda` an [annoynmous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

screen = tk.Tk() 
screen.title('This One')
screen.geometry('890x400')
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("clam")
screen.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
screen.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

cols = ('TOKEN', 'F-500', 'F-250', 'F-100', 'F-24', 'POS','NEG')
box = ttk.Treeview(screen, columns=cols, show='headings')
for col in cols:
    if col == 'TOKEN':
        box.heading(col, text=col, command =lambda: print('token'))
    box.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky='nsew')


box.column("TOKEN", width=95)
box.column("F-500", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-250", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-100", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("F-24", width=85, anchor='e')
box.column("POS", width=75, anchor='center')
box.column("NEG", width=75, anchor='center')



closeButton = tk.Button(screen, text="Close", width=15, command=exit).grid(row=10, column=0)

screen.mainloop()
```

without using lambda:

```
def token():
    print('token')

cols = ('TOKEN', 'F-500', 'F-250', 'F-100', 'F-24', 'POS','NEG')
box = ttk.Treeview(screen, columns=cols, show='headings')
for col in cols:
    if col == 'TOKEN':
        box.heading(col, text=col, command =token)
    box.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2,sticky='nsew')
```

Comment: I see!! Thanks for that, i just need to expand the if statement to include all the cols and then attach the functions! Thank you so much for your help!