# Create a lambda function with If inside a For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, lambda

I am working on some scraping on the web and I am trying to create a lambda function out of this.

The idea is that first I find all "td" in the BeautifulSoup variable I made (r_soup) and then I go deeper to search "a" and check the one that has "JPY" or "Depends on experience" in the text. That's the value I want:

```
salary = r_soup.find_all('td')
for s in salary:
    if s.find('a') and 'JPY' in s.text or s.find('a') and 'Depends on experience' in s.text:
        print(s.text.strip())
```

I have tried this:

```
salary = list(map(lambda s: s.text if (s.find('a') and 'JPY' in s.text) or (s.find('a') and 'Depends on experience') in s.text ,r_soup.find_all('td')))
salary
```

But it is not working. I don't know much about lambda functions and I have been searching on the web but to no avail.

Comment: May I suggest you take a basic tutorial on python  before jumping in to a third party library like beautiful soup which limits answers to coming from those contributors who are up to speed on this particular library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a lambda (function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try list comprehension:

```
[print(s.text.strip()) for s in r_soup.find_all('td') if s.find('a') and 'JPY' in s.text or s.find('a') and 'Depends on experience' in s.text]
```