# Function getting executed when close protocol is set in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I checked some posts on Stack Overflow on how to override the window closing event and add some logic there. But the `app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close` code makes sure the function attached is executed when the same protocol line is executed. In simple terms the code in the on_close function gets executed immediately the interpreter see the line above. You can see from the screenshot below that the method printed some words and then showed the window.
[image]

The line **exiting the application** has already been printed to the console when it's supposed to be printed when the application is dying as a result of the user clicking the close button(alias the X icon on the title bar).
This is the code am using

```py
import tkinter as tk

# function to call when user clicks close
def close_code():
    print("exiting the application")

def build_gui():
    #create a new window
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Chat App")
    window.geometry("500x500")
    window.resizable(width = False, height= False)
    window.configure(bg='white')
    #add the protocol, this line calls close code instead of waiting for user to close the app
    window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",   close_code)
  
    window.mainloop()

build_gui()
```

How do I accurately  achieve this without getting the method called when the window  is being built ?

Comment: Please correct the error in the code. `close_code()` most likely instead of `close_code`.

Comment: Then your error will not be reproduced.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66721602/13629335) related to your issue ?

Comment: @СергейКох, writing close_code() would call the function immediately. We want to just pass the function name.

Comment: What do you mean by your question?

Comment: The posted code should not call `close_code()` when the application starts.

Comment: @PortMe, what if you want to pass a parameter to the function

Comment: @SonofMan Then you use lambda functions. For example, lambda x:close_code(x)

Comment: @PortMe, am new to Python. But I resolved the issue. Let me close the question

Comment: @SonofMan It's alright :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this code is what you want to do :

```
import tkinter as tk

def close_code(window): #pass your window as param
    print("exiting the application") 
    window.destroy() #destroy your window

def build_gui():
    #create a new window
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Chat App")
    window.geometry("500x500")
    window.resizable(width = False, height= False)
    window.configure(bg='white')
    #add the protocol, this line calls close code instead of waiting for user to close the app
    window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda window=window : close_code(window)) #lambda param1=SOMETHING : fct(param1)
  
    window.mainloop()

build_gui()
```

I recommand you to use object oriented when using Tkinter :)
Have a nice day !