# How does a Lambda with instance variables work?

Tags: c#, lambda

I read through [this explanation of lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function) by [@mk.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797/mk) and it has the following example:

```
Func<int, Func<int, int>> adder = 
    (int x) => (int y) => x + y; // `int` declarations optional
Func<int, int> add5 = adder(5);
var add6 = adder(6); // Using implicit typing
Debug.Assert(add5(1) == 6);
Debug.Assert(add6(-1) == 5);

// Closure example
int yEnclosed = 1;
Func<int, int> addWithClosure = 
    (x) => x + yEnclosed;
Debug.Assert(addWithClosure(2) == 3);
```

I've used lambdas in C# for years and yet I do not understand what is going on here. Obviously this adds an instance variable, but what in the declaration is defining all this? Is x or y the instance variable? And what's with the Closure example at the bottom?

Comment: Its a delegate that returns a delegate, right?

Comment: [How to use closures in C#](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3620248/how-to-use-closures-in-csharp.html)