# if, and, elif all included within an apply(lambda x:

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, lambda

I have the below code:

```
data['ShortLongFlag'] = data['End DateTime'].apply(lambda x:
                                                   -1 if (x.month == 3 and x.date() in shortlongdates == True) else (1 if (x.month == 10 and x.date() in shortlongdates == True) else 0))
```

[image]

What I'm trying to do is the following:

Create a new column in my dataframe which is populated with either -1, 0 or 1 based on the following conditions:

- -1 if the month of the value in my datetime column is equal to 3 and the date is in my list of dates called "shortlongdates"
- 1 if the month of the value in my datetime column is equal to 10 and the date is in my list of dates called "shortlongdates"
- 0 otherwise

Right now all the values are being outputted as 0 in the new column... why?

Comment: There's really no reason why you wouldn't create a proper function here rather than trying to compress things into a `lambda`

Comment: Could you maybe share some data?

Comment: @roganjosh do you have any suggestions? Or can you explain why the lambda doesn't work? It doesn't feel that compressed to me

Comment: lambdas are functions.
 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/16509#16509  The problem is that we have to scroll like mad to read your function

Comment: I've removed the extra spaces at the end of the scroll and also included a screenshot.

Comment: @SlowlyLearning the problem isn't that we don't know how to scroll ;) but that putting everything on one line is inherently unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this problem is [chaining comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
> to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
> cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Comparisons, **including membership tests** and identity tests [have same precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

i.e.

```
x.month == 3 and x.date() in shortlongdates == True
```

is same as

```
x.month == 3 and x.date() in shortlongdates and shortlongdates == True
```

Note that it can be written as `x.month == 3 and x.date() in shortlongdates`, or use brackets. However as already stated in comments **this lambda is better written as regular function.**

```
def replace_value(x):
    if x.date() in shortlongdates:
        return {3:-1, 10:1}.get(x.month, 0)
    return 0
```

I will leave up to you to convert this back to [simpler] lambda if you insist.

Comment: Whilst I like your dict simplification at the end it might be worth pointing out how it works

Answer (score 0):

So we have this unreadable thing:

```py
lambda x: -1 if (x.month == 3 and x.date() in shortlongdates == True) else (1 if (x.month == 10 and x.date() in shortlongdates == True) else 0)
```

Let's write it out as a standard function:

```py
def filterfn(x):
    if x.month == 3 and x.date() in shortlongdates:
        return -1
    elif x.month == 10 and x.date() in shortlongdates:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

That removing some stranger tests (redundant == True) and brackets.

Is `x.date()` *really* a callable?  Should it be `x.date`?
Without seeing your `data` and `listofdates` it's impossible to say how this might fail, but at least we can see what it's doing.

Comment: Just in case OP is unsure, after defining `filterfn`, as above, it can be used as follows: `data['ShortLongFlag'] = data['End DateTime'].apply(filterfn)` i.e., where you had the lambda previously, you now just say `filterfn`.

Comment: No sense evaluating `x.date() in shortlongdates` twice; if it's false, you can return 0 immediately before even examining `x.month`.

Comment: @chepner this answer is *a very long way* from ideal. I'll probably delete it.  It merely presents what the lambda was *supposed* to do as a fn.  I deliberately avoided simplifying it, waiting for the OP to get back with the more info.  buran has the right (simplified) answer below