# function as argument for callback-function with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I am using SQLite and tkinter in Python 3.9 and got the following problem:

I got 1 SQLite DB with 2 tables.

I am using the column of one of the tables for a tkinter option menu.
Now I want to trace the variable selected and display a corresponding value from the other table on a `tk.label`. OptionMenu and label are in the same window.

This is what I tried but returns:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

```
def callBackFct(var):
        cur.execute("""SELECT nameFromColumn FROM sqlDbTable WHERE condition = ?""", (var,))
        f = cur.fetchall()
        tkLabel1.config(text = f[0][0])

optionMenuVar1.trace("w", callBackFct(optionMenuVar1.get()))
```

If I let the function get the variable like this...

```
def callBackFct(*args):
        var = optionMenuVar1.get() # getting variable inside function
        cur.execute("""SELECT nameFromColumn FROM sqlDbTable WHERE condition = ?""", (var,))
        f = cur.fetchall()
        tkLabel1.config(text = f[0][0])

optionMenuVar1.trace("w", callBackFct))
```

it works, but I have 50 labels and dont want to copy + paste 50 functions. There hast to be a more elegant solution right, where I can give an argument to the callback function?!
Please help. It seems like I have missunderstood something basic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every function in python needs to return something. So when you do this `callBackFct(optionMenuVar1.get())` **callBackFct returns None** since it returns nothing else. *lambda is a way to store a function with provided arguments* and is not [executed when declared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771787/13629335).

You can use an [annonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314) for this case.

```
import tkinter as tk
def test(x):
    print(x)
root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
opt = tk.OptionMenu(root,var,value='hi')
opt.pack()
var.trace('w',lambda *args:test(var.get()))

root.mainloop()
```

Another maybe easier way to understand is to follow this [Tutorial/Documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracing-tkinter-variables-in-python/) here. Which could lead to the following code for you:

```
def callBackFct(var,idx,mod):
        cur.execute("""SELECT nameFromColumn FROM sqlDbTable WHERE condition = ?""", (var.get(),))
        f = cur.fetchall()
        tkLabel1.config(text = f[0][0])

optionMenuVar1.trace("w", callBackFct))
```

Comment: Thanks that works as intended.
But why does it work contrary to my attempts?

Comment: @Stogi every function in python needs to return something. So when you do this `callBackFct(optionMenuVar1.get())` callBackFct returns `None` since it returns nothing else. lambda is a way to store a function with provided arguments and is [not executed when declared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771787/13629335).