# Tkinter keep name string after .delete operation

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a simple program in Python and Tkinter.

The Program shows and Entrybox for your name, put's out a welcome sentence with your name and deletes the content of the Entrybox.

Unfortunately the name itsself is deleted too, so I can't call it later in other sentences. The output of Q1_1 misses the name.

How can I fix that?

```
#NameInfo
NameInfo = ttk.Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text="Bitte geben Sie zuerst Ihren (eigenen) Namen ein:")
NameInfo.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
#Name
name = tk.StringVar()
getname = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=name)
getname.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
#SaveName
SaveName = ttk.Button(root, text="Speichern", command=lambda: DisplayWelcome())
SaveName.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)

#DisplayWelcome
def DisplayWelcome():
    global DisplayWelcome1
    DisplayWelcome1 = ttk.Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text=(str('Hallo, ' + name.get() + ' :)')))
    DisplayWelcome1.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
    global DisplayWelcome2
    DisplayWelcome2 = ttk.Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text="xxx")
    DisplayWelcome2.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
    global DisplayWelcome3
    DisplayWelcome3 = ttk.Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text="xxx")
    DisplayWelcome3.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
    global ForwardButton
    ForwardButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Weiter", command=lambda: ForwardButtonClicked())
    ForwardButton.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
    getname.delete(0,'end')

#ForwardButtonClicked
def ForwardButtonClicked():
    HelloInfo1.grid_remove()
    HelloInfo2.grid_remove()
    img_label.grid_remove()
    NameInfo.grid_remove()
    getname.grid_remove()
    SaveName.grid_remove()
    DisplayWelcome1.grid_remove()
    DisplayWelcome2.grid_remove()
    DisplayWelcome3.grid_remove()
    ForwardButton.grid_remove()
    global Q1_1
    Q1_1 = ttk.Label(root, font=("Calibri", 14), text=(str('Ok, ' + name.get() + ' xxx')))
    Q1_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.NW, padx=0, pady=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the issue in your code:

```
getname.delete(0,'end')
```

not just clears your Entry it clears your StingVar() defined here too:

```
name = tk.StringVar()
getname = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=name)
```

The Entry writes the content of it in the textvariable/StringVar.
So deleting this line `getname.delete(0,'end')` will solve your problem, since you `grid_remove` it anyway.

Also you seem a little bit confused here:

```
SaveName = ttk.Button(root, text="Speichern", command=lambda: DisplayWelcome())
ForwardButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Weiter", command=lambda: ForwardButtonClicked())
```

[lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314) is a usefull tool, but just use it if its really needed (e.g. [predefined arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter))

In addition, since you seem a beginner. I would recommand you to follow [a good tutorial for tkinter](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6lxxT7IdTxGoHfouzEK-dFcwr_QClME_) and learn about [OOP](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) and [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to avoid [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil).