# call a function if the frame widget gets the focus in python(tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, focus, frame

In `working.py`  , I get the focused frame using `focus()`.
In `calculations.py`, I am trying to run some calculations which depends on which frame is focused.
I am calling `calculations()` on btn which is in `main.py`.

What I am trying to achieve is that when I click `Calculate` button,
if `e1_frame` is focused I should get the addition of 2 numbers and
when `e2_frame` is focused I should get the multiplication of those 2 numbers.

But instead I get the following error:
`TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'`

### main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from working import create_frames
from calculations import calculations


class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        self.var_e1 = StringVar(None)
        self.var_e2 = StringVar(None)
        self.var_lbl = StringVar(None)
        self.var_status_lbl = StringVar(None)

        create_frames(self)

        e1 = Entry(self.e1_frame, textvariable=self.var_e1)
        e2 = Entry(self.e2_frame, textvariable=self.var_e2)
        e1.focus_set()

        e1.pack()
        e2.pack()

        btn = Button(self.btn_frame, text='Calculate', command=lambda e: calculations(self, e))
        btn.pack()

        lbl = Label(self.root, font=20, textvariable=self.var_lbl)
        self.var_lbl.set('0')
        lbl.pack()

        status_lbl = Label(self.root, textvariable=self.var_status_lbl)
        status_lbl.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.var_status_lbl.set('Nothing is selected.')

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('400x400')
    MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### working.py

```
from tkinter import *

def focus(self, event):
    if event.widget == self.e1_frame:
        self.var_status_lbl.set(f'First value: {self.var_e1.get()}')
    if event.widget == self.e2_frame:
        self.var_status_lbl.set(f'Second value: {self.var_e2.get()}')
    
def create_frames(self):
    e0_frame = Frame(self.root)
    self.e1_frame = Frame(e0_frame)
    self.e2_frame = Frame(e0_frame)
    
    e0_frame.pack()
    self.e1_frame.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.e2_frame.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.btn_frame = Frame(self.root)
    self.btn_frame.pack(pady=10)

    self.e1_frame.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: focus(self, e))
    self.e2_frame.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: focus(self, e))
```

### calculations.py

```
from tkinter import *

def calculations(self, event):
    value1 = int(self.var_e1.get())
    value2 = int(self.var_e2.get())

    if event.widget == self.e1_frame:
        result = value1 + value2
    if event.widget == self.e2_frame:
        result = value1 * value2

    result = value1 + value2
    self.var_lbl.set(result)
```

Comment: buttons don't send an event object to the callback.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, Ok. Then how do I get the results I want?

Answer (score 0):

This line seems problematic to me:

```
lambda e: calculations(self, e)
```

While you define a [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function/62742314#62742314) for a button command you set the argument `e` which commonly stands for *event*, which refers to an [EvenObject](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-handlers.html) produced by tkinter and passed as argument to the bounded function/method.

Enough of the context and lets see how we can fix your code. I would suggest to make `calculation` an ordinary method and leave that event object for cases where it is more needed. You can simply get which entry has the *[keyboard focus](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/focus.html)* by calling [focus_get()](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/focus.html), which can easily replace your `event.widget` if statement.

```
import tkinter as tk

def cmd():
    print(root.focus_get())

root = tk.Tk()
e1 = tk.Entry()
e2 = tk.Entry()
b1 = tk.Button(command=cmd)

e1.pack()
e2.pack()
b1.pack()
```

Comment: I thought about using this method. But how am I supposed to use this method in my if statements in calculations.py

Comment: @MilindKhobragade `event.widget` would return a widget reference as `focus_get` does. I dont see the problem here.

Comment: `focus_get()` is working well with the entries, but not with the frames.
In my original code I've several widgets(frames, entries, labels, ComboBoxes) in that frame. And I've many such frames. I don't want to select specific entry from specific frame each time when I calculate.

Comment: @MilindKhobragade then your question isnt clear und you should have pointed that out in your question.

Comment: @ Thingamabobs, sorry to say, but I did mention about focused frame widget in my question

Comment: @MilindKhobragade you allready save which frame is entered with `self.var_status_lbl.set`. Why dont you `get` it and compare it in this case?

Comment: I tried it like this in `calculations.py`, `if self.var_status_lbl.get() == self.var_e1.get():`, I don't get any errors but nothing happens when I calculate.

Comment: `self.var_status_lbl.set(self.e1_frame)` in `working.py` and then compare it in `calculation.py` like this `if self.var_status_lbl.get() == str(self.e1_frame):`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239841/discussion-between-milind-khobragade-and-thingamabobs).