# Understanding Python Lambda behavior with Tkinter Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-button

I would like to understand how a button is working using lambda.
I have the following Python code:

```
from tkinter import *

def comando_click(mensagem):
    print(mensagem)

menu_inicial = Tk()
menu_inicial.geometry("500x250+200+200")

botao = Button(menu_inicial, text = "Executar", command=comando_click("Nova_Mensagem"))
botao.pack()

menu_inicial.mainloop()
```

But my button doesn't work when I click on it, it only shows the print once in the console when I run the code, I added some prints here in the question:

[Problem Picture one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKkPI.png)

Well it seems that when I use the Lambda function in the button it works and I really would like to know why.

[Lambda working button Picture one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EivYF.png)

I just added to the button the lambda :

```
botao = Button(menu_inicial, text = "Executar", command=lambda:comando_click("Nova_Mensagem"))
```

[Lambda working button Picture two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVTAU.png)

Why with lambda it works?
It shoudn't work without lambda too since lambda is basically a anonymous function?

I am extremely curious to understand why it works, thank you all for the help :)

Edit: I would like to thank you guys, now I finally understand what was going on and how Python was working. Thank you all very much :D

Comment: You might find that [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742314/13629335)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `()` with a function name(`func(args)`), then it is immediately calling/invoking the function while python is executing the line, you do not want that. You want to ONLY call the function when the button is clicked. `tkinter` will internally call the function for you, all you have to do is give the function name.

**Why use `lambda`?** Think of it as a function that returns another function, your code can be lengthened to:

```
func  = lambda: comando_click("Nova_Mensagem")
botao = Button(menu_inicial, text = "Executar", command=func)
```

`func` is the function name and if you want to call it, you would say `func()`. And when you say `command=comando_click("Nova_Mensagem")` then `command` has the value returned by `command click`(because you call the function with `()`), which is `None` and if I'm not wrong, if the given value is `None`, it will not be called by `tkinter`. Hence your function is executed just once because of `()` and as a result of calling the function, you are assigning the value of the function call(`None`) before the event loop starts processing the events.

**Some other methods:**

- Using `partial` from `functools`:

```
from functools import partial

botao = Button(.....,command=partial(comando_click,"Nova_Mensagem"))
```

- Using a *helper* function:

```
def helper(args):
    def comando_click():
        print(args)

    return comando_click

botao = Button(...., command=helper("Nova_Mensagem"))
```

IMO, `lambda`s are the easiest way to proceed with calling a function with arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
command=comando_click("Nova_Mensagem")
```

you have called the `comando_click` function, once, and assigned the result (`None`) to the `command` argument.  Nothing will happen when `command` is called (in fact you should get a `TypeError` exception because `None` is not callable).

In this code:

```
command=lambda:comando_click("Nova_Mensagem")
```

you have not actually called `comando_click` yet -- you have created a new function (using `lambda`) that will in turn call `comando_click` when it is called.  Every time the button is clicked, your new function will get called.

If the `lambda` is confusing, you can do the exact same thing with a `def` like this:

```
def button_command():
    comando_click("Nova_Mensagem")

...

command=button_command  # no ()!  we don't want to actually call it yet!
```

The `lambda` expression is just an alternative to using `def` when you want to create a small single-use function that doesn't need a name (e.g. you want to make a function that calls another function with a specific argument, exactly as you're doing here).

Comment: _"..in fact you should get a TypeError exception because None is not callable.."_: I do not think `tkinter` will bother calling a `NoneType` object anyway

Comment: seems like an antifeature in tkinter imo (it should let you know that you typo'd your button definition) but I've never used it :)

Comment: @Samwise: it's not an antifeature. There are reasons you might want or need to set the command to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that with `comando_click("Nova_Mensagem")` you are executing the function. So command=None.

In the second case `lambda:comando_click("Nova_Mensagem")` is returning a lambda, that internally calls `comando_click("Nova_Mensagem")`.

Fix: just put `command=comando_click`.

If you want to personalize the lambda with arguments you could write something like this:

```
def handler(args):
    def custom_handler():
        print(args)
    return custom_handler

botao = Button(menu_inicial, text = "Executar", command=handler("my custom string"))
```